# Crash when delete QGraphicsItem

Tags: qt, assembly

I want to remove all items in QGraphicsScene and delete them. Like this,

```
QGraphicsItem * item = NULL;
foreach(item, scene->items())
{
    scene->removeItem(item);
    delete item;
}
```

However, it crashed with a segmentation fault just after running this block of codes and getting out from the loop. And in debug mode, the debugger jumped to an assembly file:
[image]
What's going wrong?

Comment: Does it still crash if you use `item->deleteLater()` instead of `delete item`?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight -- I'm pretty sure that's not the issue in this case as the items in question are of type `QGraphicsItem*` and `QGraphicsItem` doesn't inherit from `QObject`.  It certainly smacks of memory corruption though.

Comment: I take my comment regarding `deleteLater` back -- to a certain extent.  If the code shown executes within the context of an event handler and one or more of the deleted items are actually of a type derived from `QGraphicsObject` then `QObject::deleteLater` *would* be appropriate for those items.  Otherwise they may be deleted with events still pending.  Also, if you're removing/deleting all items why not simply use [`QGraphicsScene::clear`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#clear)

Answer (score 1):

it's because qt used a BSP Tree index to lookup items more efficiently.

1. you can use `removeFromIndex()` in `CustomItem`'s deconstructor to remove the item from BSP Tree.
2. or you can use `m_scene->setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene::NoIndex);` to disable QGraphicsScene using BSP Tree ;

1 is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deleting all the items from the scene, why dont you do "clear" as shown below.
You have scene object with you right.

scene-> clear();

As per the documentation:
void QGraphicsScene::clear()

Removes and deletes all items from the scene, but otherwise leaves the state of the scene unchanged.

This function was introduced in Qt 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks OK to me, but I agree that just using QGraphicsScene::clear makes more sense; it does exactly this and my guess is that it's more efficient.

If you've derived your own QGraphicsItem objects, then check the destructors in your derived classes for multiple memory deletion. You may have confusion over which object owns a particular pointer, resulting in two different items freeing the same memory.

Answer (score 0):

You use Pointers and when you use the function clear it calls the destructor of daughters but with pointers you have to destroy all pointers. Don't use foreach, try with a simple for loop, because foreach uses iterators and i think that iterator is invalid after deletion.

```
for(int i=0; i < v.size(); ++i)
{
     delete v[i];
     v[i] = nullptr ;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but someone might find it useful.

I've had this problem multiple times and not just when deleting items but also when changing item's position or dimensions.

What worked every single time was simply adding

```
item->prepareGeometryChange();
```

before doing any deleting/changing dimensions.

Why? No idea.